# My codeiginter project not worked without index.php in online

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

My Codeigniter project worked well in localhost (i am using linux Cpanel)

https://localhost/project/profile

But without index.php in link it does not work online

https://domainname.in/index.php/profile

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and my **route.php** file

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['pages/profile'] = "pages/profile"; 
$route['creators'] = "pages/userList";
$route['auth/logout'] = "auth/logout";
$route['auth'] = "auth/logout";
$route['auth/login'] = "auth/login";
$route['auth/register'] = "auth/register";
$route['pages/post'] = "pages/post";
$route[$username.'/about'] = "pages/menus/about";
$route[$username.'/credibility'] = "pages/menus/credibility";
$route[$username.'/release'] = "pages/menus/release";
$route[$username.'/jobs'] = "pages/menus/jobs";
$route[$username] = "pages/userList/userview/$1";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeiginter product worked well in localserver without index.php but not worked in server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906066/codeiginter-product-worked-well-in-localserver-without-index-php-but-not-worked)

Answer (score 0):

please try with this. hopefully it will work.

update with your root .htaccess.txt file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Where to place the htaccess files in main folder or application folder

Comment: .htaccess.text file not show in server. you have need to update in your localhost or your pc then have need to upload in server. please try in this way . It's a working version in our server.

Comment: Still having problem. Index.php not removed from URL

Comment: flow this step:<br/>
Open config.php and do following replaces
<br/>
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
<br/>
to
<br/>
$config['index_page'] = ""
<br/>
In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace
<br/>
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"

by

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
<br/>
then check your apache that is it enable rewrite mod<br/>

Comment: i already changed this. And how to check rewrite mode is enable or not.. I saw in php_info() on xampp window its shows.. My site link streetrelease.in please visit

Comment: pls help me @Jahid Hasan

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file inside your project folder i hope it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectfoldername/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectfoldername/index.php/$1 [L]
```