# Codeiginter product worked well in localserver without index.php but not worked in server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

I have created one project in codeiginiter

That was worked in local server without index.php (localhost/sample)
But when i up-ed into online server(cpanel linux) the default controller only worked , other next page URLs are not worked.. (https://sample/nextpage)

if i give index.php means worked (https://sample/index.php/nextpage)

i want to remove index.php , please help me..

my config.php

```
$config['index_page']   = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

my **route.php** file

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/home";
$route['pages/profile'] = "pages/profile"; 
$route['creators'] = "pages/userList";
$route[$username] = "pages/userList/userview/$1"; 

$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
Options All -Indexes
```

Thanks in Advance,

Shruthi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the code of your .htaccess file with the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Lot of  Thanks!... Coming sunday my project launching date.. You only saved me. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

Change .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /name of project folder 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am not having project folder on online server.. Upload under public_html

Comment: Not an issue u can skip that line .

Comment: Flag u used was not proper ...refer this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Can't to understand that link

Comment: Ok ..for now just skip 2nd line and let me know if it work for u or not

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|public|tmp|download|javascript|rte|document|xajax_js|robots\.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please contact your hosting provider and check mod_rewrite module is enable or not?

Comment: Got by @sarvagna answer